# Can't add tables in Entity Model without Primary key

Tags: entity-framework, primary-key, ado.net-entity-data-model, composite-primary-key

I have a problem in using Entity data model. I'm unable to add a table in entity model that has no primary key. The same situation is with the table that has composite key.

Comment: A table with no primary key is not really a table ... every real, regular table **must have** a primary key....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For composite keys sure you are wrong but for the first one How could a framework like Entity Framework could know which row has been updated, deleted while it can not identify the row by a primary key,

even in that tables you can have exact duplicate rows.

For the first one check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925632/composite-db-keys-with-entity-framework-4-0)

Comment: So the solution is the third column (primary key)?

Comment: Yeah, or making one of existing columns PK if it applies, for the first case add and ID column with `GUID` type with default `newid()` that can make you free of generating it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Change the Table structure and add a Primary Column. Update the Model.

2.Modify the .EDMX file in XML Editor and try adding a New Column under tag for this specific table. (WILL NOT WORK)

3.Instead of creating a new Primary Column to Exiting table, i will make a composite key by involving all the existing columns.(WORKED)

[Entity Framework: Adding DataTable with no Primary Key to Entity Model.](http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.in/2012/04/entity-framework-adding-datatable-with.html)